# Error "An invalid IP address was specified" when typed a number below "100" in 2nd and 3rd part

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
    private void TestConnect()
    {
        while (t.IsAlive)
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("187.84.191.50"), 80));
                this.Invoke(new SetLabel(SetLabelStatus), "Open connection, active host.");
            }
            catch (SocketException ex) { this.Invoke(new SetLabel(SetLabelStatus), "Unable to connect, error: \n" + ex.Message + "\nTrying again..."); }
            finally { client.Close(); }
        }
    }
```

It works fine when I type an address like 173.194.118.71 (a.k. Google), but if I type an address like this: 187.84.191.50
The error "An invalid IP address was specified" returns to code.

So how can I cast the IP address correctly using the IPAddress.Parse() method?

Comment: Do you even need the IPAddress.Parse? normally .Connect("IP ADDY") works fine.

Comment: `client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("187.84.191.50"), 80));` should be `client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("187.84.191.50"), 80);` Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: your code runs fine for me, after fixing the syntax problems

Comment: `IPAddress.Parse("187.84.191.50")` does not throw an exception for me.  Neither does `client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("187.84.191.50"), 80))`

Comment: I strongly suspect that you have a comma that has leaked into your address and it just happened to be when you changed the IP address. Can you post the code that actually fails to verify this?

Comment: Maybe my application is filling with 0 in the left of address, i.e.: 187.94.116.50, it is writing 187.095.116.50

Answer (score 2):

The code above is working fine, the problem is occurring when I type an address starting with "0" before number in second part, that can't cast correctly. So, i treated it with this code:

```
                string ip = (Convert.ToInt16(txtIP.Text.Replace(",", ".").Split('.')[0])).ToString();
                ip += "." + (Convert.ToInt16(txtIP.Text.Replace(",", ".").Split('.')[1])).ToString();
                ip += "." + (Convert.ToInt16(txtIP.Text.Replace(",", ".").Split('.')[2])).ToString();
                ip += "." + (Convert.ToInt16(txtIP.Text.Replace(",", ".").Split('.')[3])).ToString();
                client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
```